# Directive not working anymore passing to Angular 1.3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

Yesterday, I have updated Angular Js to latest version 1.3 but a simple directive that just put the focus to an input text doesn't work anymore. Here the code in coffeescript:

```
# activate the focus to an element
angular.module('dbManagerApp').directive 'riumFocusOn', ->

    scope:
        trigger: '=riumFocusOn'
    link: (scope, elem, attr) ->

        scope.$watch 'trigger', (value) ->

            elem[0].focus() if value
```

Debugging the code, it pass through the focus() method as before but in the web page the cursor not appear.
Can anyone help me to understand why it stopped working? Taking a look to the Angular's changelog, I haven't seen any point that can include my problem.

**UPDATE**

Here the example [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mJV5S9rkXenSMP8ZgoaG?p=preview)

I would like that after pressing the "Add item" link, the focus going to the input text that will appear below. I tried to change Angular to 1.2 but is still not working in Plunker but in my project works..

Comment: Show your HTML, and how you use the directive. Maybe you can make a demo with a problem?

Comment: i think your problem is related to something else, i tried to reproduce this but it works for me http://plnkr.co/edit/m6N1rKPrk50f3sZcfGrM?p=preview

Comment: I have added the example, maybe the problem isn't the new version of Angular but something else...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the directive in this way:

```
app.directive('riumFocusOn', function() {
    return {
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        var model = attrs.riumFocusOn;

        scope.$watch(model, function(value) {
          if (value === true) {
              setTimeout(function() {
                 elem[0].focus();
              }, 200);

          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Now It works fine as before to update to Angular 1.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what you're watching with your $watch on 'trigger', but if it's just about autofocusing an element when it's beeing shown you could always use "autofocus" if it's okay that it won't work in < ie10.

```
<input autofocus id="edit--menu__input" rium-escape-input="" ... />
```

Comment: consider that I have multiple lists with the "add item" (like the example on plunker) on my page and other input text. The page is quit complex. I tried to add the autofocus but is still not working... thanks

Comment: did you try combining it with ng-if instead of ng-show?